# UIImageView in customCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have problem, I have got xib based custom cell and I want to show imageview there.

Tried this:

```
UIImageView *flag1;
UIImageView *flag2;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *flag1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *flag2;
```

Connect it in IB

and this:

```
 cell.flag1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[rowData objectForKey:@"Flag1"]];
```

How to fix it to get it working?

Thanks

Comment: Where does connection originate from? The File owner, or the cell itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set an IBOutlet. Only IB sets IBOutlets. So in this case, what you meant to say is:

```
cell.flag1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[rowData objectForKey:@"Flag1"]];
```

You should be receiving warnings in your code, complaining about a type mismatch. Be sure to pay attention to these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.flag1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[rowData objectForKey:@"Flag1"]];` isn't right. You are assigning a UIImage to a UIImageView.

`[cell.flag1 setImage:...]` is the right code for this